# What is default (factory pre-loaded) iOS for iPhone 3gs

Tags: iphone, ios

I was so happy with my iphone when I bought it. It was so fast... now, after dozen of upgrades i hate my iphone....

does anyone remember what was the original version of iOS when they bought their 3GS

Comment: It will be different for everyone based on the time when you bought your phone.

Comment: Lastest iOS 4 for iPhone 3GS really are slowest than lastest iOS 3 ?

Comment: @Bil_fr Not sure that I understood?

Comment: 3gs appears to be locked - you can't downgrade....

Comment: unless you have shsh files? is that true?

Comment: Try a clean install of iOS 4, and avoid apps which do stuff in the background, and disable features like spotlight.

Answer (score 1):

The 3GS originally shipped with iOS 3.0, which was called iPhone OS 3.0 at the time.

Answer (score 1):

The 3GS is still available for sale today, and it ships with the latest version of iOS 4 pre-installed.

The 3GS was launched within a few days of iOS 3.0's launch, so for a long time it was sold with that pre-installed.

So the answer depends on when you bought your phone. But it should not be slow with the latest version of iOS. I know several people running iOS 4 on their 3GS without any problems.

Comment: yeah.. don't upgrade from 4.3.3 it's the latest speedy version

Answer (score 0):

Some iPhone 3GSs even come with iOS 5 preinstalled. Before that, the 8 gb models would come with iOS 4 installed. Before that, they came with iOS 3. That's the list of preinstalled iOSs. The 16 and 32 gig models only came with iOS 3. Sadly, they were discontinued on September 12th , 2012.

Answer (score -1):

go to 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone

and then go to 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history